# How to move a circle on canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I try to move a circle on canvas using `requestAnimationFrame`.
Circle moves while i move a mouse. But other previous circles are drawn too.
What should i do to erase previous sprites?

I draw using `arc(x, y, 15, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is "clearRect"

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Call it before your

```
arc(x, y, 15, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
```

---

**What is happening:**
The canvas does not clear itself before drawing the next frame. So anything you draw will stay there until you call "clearRect()"

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely what i'm looking for.